# SQl Server - Where clause uses maximum date in data

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling with something i thought would be easy.

I have a table that is updated via an append on most days and has a report date field that shows the date the rows were updated.

I want to join to this table but only pull back the records from the date the table was last updated

Most of the time I could get away just looking for yesterdays date as the table is updated most days

```
Where [reportdate] > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

But as its not always updated daily, I wanted to rule this issue out. Is there anyway of returning the max date?

I was trying to figure out max (date), but I can't figure out the grouping. I need to return all the fields. The below just seems to return the whole table

```
SELECT max ([ReportDate]) as reportdate
      ,[GUID]
      ,[Make]
      ,[Model]
      ,[MPxN]
      ,[PaymentMode]
      ,[Consent]
      ,[Category]
      ,[Fuel]
      ,[pkCommCompID]

  FROM table
  
group by guid
,[Make]
      ,[Model]
      ,[MPxN]
      ,[PaymentMode]
      ,[Consent]
      ,[Category]
      ,[Fuel]
      ,[pkCommCompID]
```

I could get round it with a temp table that just has the max report date and then using this as the left part of a join

```
SELECT max ([ReportDate]) as reportdate

  FROM [DOMCustomers].[dbo].[DCC_Device_Comms_Compiled]
```

But The SQL is triggered in Excel so temp tables are problematic (i think).

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Store the max reportdate client-side, then pass it back as a param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway of returning the max date?

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
where ReportDate = (select max(ReportDate) from SomeTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a `DENSE_RANK` and `TOP` would work (assuming `ReportDate` is a `date`):

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       [ReportDate]
      ,[GUID]
      ,[Make]
      ,[Model]
      ,[MPxN]
      ,[PaymentMode]
      ,[Consent]
      ,[Category]
      ,[Fuel]
      ,[pkCommCompID]
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ReportDate DESC);
```

If `ReportDate` is a date and time value, and you want everything for the latest date (ignoring time), then replace `ReportDate` with `CONVERT(date,ReportDate)` in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Isn't the `ORDER BY` clause equivalent to just `ORDER BY ReportDate`?

Comment: Probably, in retrospect, @GMB . I was winding down the day when I wrote the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual example.

It will produce a latest row for each car make.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, make VARCHAR(20), ReportDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl (make, ReportDate) VALUES
('Ford', '2020-12-31'),
('Ford', '2020-10-17'),
('Tesla', '2020-10-25'),
('Tesla', '2020-12-30');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY make ORDER BY ReportDate DESC) AS seq
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1;
```